# What is the best/easiest way to create ZIP archive in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, zip

Which method do you think is the "best".

- Use the `System.IO.Packaging` namespace?
- Use interop with the Shell?
- Third party library for .NET?
- Interop with open source unmanaged DLL?

[I can target Framework 3.5; best = easiest to design, implement, and maintain.]

I am mostly interested in why you think the chosen approach is best.

Comment: If you find this question and use .NET 4.5 or above, check out Sheridan's answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23560331/434742

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've always used [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)

Forgot the why part:  Mainly because its been around for a long time.  It is well documented, and has an intuitive API.  Plus it's open source if you're into that type of thing.

Comment: Well documented? I found no usable documentation whatsoever, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Also, SharpZipLib is licensed under GPL - so you might not want to use it in commercial applications. However, you should not have any problem using it in Open Source applications.

Comment: it is really convoluted that lib ;(

Answer (score 16):

I've found the [DotNetZip Library](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip/) to be this easiest way to work with zip files. [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) is a far more powerful and flexible solution.

Comment: I used to be a big fan of that lib too until I ended up with corrupted files. The issue is not considered as critical by the project owners and the project seems no longer active (no updates/fixes since more than 2 years), however, a workaround is available, see: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/14087

Answer (score 16):

[DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) is very simple to use. I like it because it is fully-managed - no shell interaction required.  The programming model is simpler and cleaner than that for the shell.  Also it is simpler than SharpZipLib as well as the Packaging classes added in .NET 3.0.  It is free, small, actively maintained.

It is much better than the J# option that one poster offered - J# is a huge runtime and a giant pill to swallow to get just ZIP support.  Also J# support is being discontinued.  Probably not a good idea to introduce new dependencies on J#.

Example code for DotNetZip:

```
  try
  {
      using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(args[0], System.Console.Out))
      {
          zip.AddDirectory(args[1]); // recurses subdirectories
          zip.Save();
      }
  }
  catch (System.Exception ex1)
  {
      System.Console.Error.WriteLine("exception: " + ex1);
  }
```

DotNetZip works with .NET v2.0, 3.0, 3.5 as well as Compact Framework v2.0 and 3.5. It does ZIP files, Unicode filenames, comments, passwords.  It does ZIP64 as well as Self-extracting archives.  It's FAST.  Try it.

Comment: Very easy to use API and well document.  Cannot go wrong with this one.

Comment: except it messes up with files that have cyrillic symbols in a filename.

Comment: Not really @chester89, it works with UTF-8 filenames. Check the documentation for unicode. You need to set the unicode flag to do this; the reason for this is that unicode was not widely used in zip tools at the time this library was created. Not even winzip supported unicode. Not even the spec. So unicode was left as an opt-in.  just google for "dotnetzip unicode" and you'll find code samples.

Comment: @Cheeso ok, I'll take a look. Was really surprised when my code didn't work as I expected. Thanks

Comment: I used to be a big fan of that lib too until I ended up with corrupted files. The issue is not considered as critical by the project owners and the project seems no longer active (no updates/fixes since more than 2 years), however, a workaround is available, see: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/14087

Answer (score 16):

I realise that this is an old question now, but I just thought I'd add a more up to date answer. If you are using .NET 4.5, then you can programmatically save multiple files into a zip folder easily using the new built in [`ZipFile` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

First, you'll need to prepare your files into a new folder (`Directory.CreateDirectory`, `File.Move`) and then you can simply use the [`ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485707%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (adapted from the linked page):

```
string filePathOfNewFolder = @"c:\example\start";
string zipFilePath = @"c:\example\result.zip";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(filePathOfNewFolder, zipFilePath);
```

Comment: +1 for updating an old question with a new answer (and better one at that).

Comment: Remark: zipFilePath cannot be located within the specified folder or ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory will throw a file used by another process exception.

Comment: @Sheridan: i have used .NET 4.5 ZipFile class as suggested here. The zipped file size is 25Mb. i want to split the zipped file in to 10Mb each. could you please help me out to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

The GZipStream and DeflateStream classes under System.IO.Compression namespace make it pretty easy to zip things up.

UPDATE:
Comments correctly state that these classes do not allow you to manipulate a Zip file.  However, the J# dlls contain the required functionality in java.util and java.io namespaces.  For more details see the [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/cpzipstrip2.aspx) by dmihailescu which details their use and provides sample code.

Comment: IIRC: These are just compression algorithm, and do not allow for archiving (multiple compressed entries)

Comment: Like Greg said. They don't create ZIP archives. Only GZipped streaming, which is useful for http file transfer, compressing your own file formats, etc. But not for creating zip files.

Comment: Don't use the J# dlls to read/write zip files.  Why?  Let me count the ways:  J# is out of support.  The J# runtime is HUGE.  The library is not very .NET-oriented (no events, no properties, no Dispose, etc).  The zip implementation is old, incomplete (no support for zip passwords, no ZIP64, etc), and buggy.  Use a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2):

No one has mentioned the [Xceed](http://xceed.com) Zip component.  I've used it before and it worked excellent for creating zip files and compressing data streams. I highly recommend it but there may be a license fee tradeoff.

Comment: Indeed, the license fee is why I didn't recommend it - while it works great, so does SharpZipLib, which is free.

Comment: The SharpZipLib is licensed under modified GPL which can cause problems in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're targetting Framework 3.5, I'd go with `System.IO.Packaging`. It's a library designed specifically for zipping, and comes with the framework so there's not even an extra DLL needed by the product. The usage example is atrocious, though.

Using the shell is unrecommended. First, it would only work on Windows XP and above. But even if you don't care about that, it's pitfalls are quite numerous (I've done it before, but only because I really had no choice).

if you're not targetting 3.5, I'd use [`SharpZipLib`](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/). It's quite a good library, and even if you are using 3.5 you might consider it.

Comment: System.IO.Packaging is for reading/writing new Office 2007 formats and was developed with this in mind. E.g. it is not a general zip implementation and has a couple of limitations for that matter.

Comment: Can you elaborate on these limitations? I haven't yet used that library and would like some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimate ZIP is a high-performance and reliable compression component which lets you easily create and manipulate ZIP, TAR, TGZ, GZ archives on-the-fly as well as browse the contents of a previously created archive right in your .NET cross-platform apps. Written purely in C# with the best design patterns and low-level .NET optimizations applied, it offers performance, reliability and extensibility to your .NET applications. The package comes with a number of code snipets and fully documented examples in VB.NET and C# illustrating how to create, zip and unzip archives.

[Ultimate ZIP component for .NET](http://www.thedownloadplanet.com/reviews/review-zip-professional-bundle-net-and-mobile/)

Comment: Link is down :(