# .Net Zip Up files

Tags: c#, .net, zip

Whats the best way to zip up files using C#? Ideally I want to be able to seperate files into a single archive.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384955/best-easiest-way-to-create-zip-archive-in-net

Comment: @Ruben: then vote to close ...

Comment: [You should stop worrying and love dupes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to archieve this. It´s free to use in any application.

Here´s some sample code:

```
   try
   {
     // for easy disposal
     using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
     {
       // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
       zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
       // add the report into a different directory in the archive
       zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
       zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
       zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
     }
   }
   catch (System.Exception ex1)
   {
     System.Console.Error.WriteLine("exception: " + ex1);
   }
```

Comment: ps: I just added a multi-threaded deflate to DotNetZip.  Because deflate is compute-intensive, using multiple threads makes it significantly faster on large files, when running on multi-core machines. In my measurements, it can cut 45% of the time from zipping a large archive, as compared to DotNetZip without the multi-thread support.  And the programming model is no different - it's the same code on the outside.  It's only the internals that have changed.  You need v1.9.0.29 to get this speedup.

Answer (score 7):

#### This is now built into the framework if you have version 4.5+

Otherwise, use Ionic.

Namespace is `System.IO.Packaging.ZIPPackage`.

See http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/05/21/net-framework-gets-zip.aspx for a story.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/)?

I believe you *can* build zip files with classes in the [`System.IO.Packaging`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) namespace - but every time I've tried to look into it, I've found it rather confusing...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this library:
http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/

It is pretty comprehensive, it deals with many formats, is open-source, and you can use in closed-source commercial applications.

It is very simple to use:

```
byte[] data1 = new byte[...];
byte[] data2 = new byte[...];
/*...*/

var path = @"c:\test.zip";
var zip = new ZipOutputStream(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                IsStreamOwner = true
            }

zip.PutNextEntry("File1.txt");
zip.Write(data1, 0, data1.Length);

zip.PutNextEntry("File2.txt");
zip.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);

zip.Close();
zip.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few librarys around - the most popular of which are [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) and [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/).

Answer (score 0):

Hi i created two methods with the ShapLib library (you can download it here http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) that would like to share, they are very easy to use just pass source and target path (fullpath including folder/file and extension). Hope it help you!

```
//ALLYOURNAMESPACESHERE
using ...

//SHARPLIB
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.Compression.Streams;

public static class FileUtils
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourcePath"></param>
    /// <param name="targetPath"></param>
    public static void ZipFile(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        string tempZipFilePath = targetPath;
        using (FileStream tempFileStream = File.Create(tempZipFilePath, 1024))
        {
            using (ZipOutputStream zipOutput = new ZipOutputStream(tempFileStream))
            {
                // Zip with highest compression.
                zipOutput.SetLevel(9);
                DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(sourcePath);
                foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
                {

                    // Get local path and create stream to it.
                    String localFilename = file.FullName;
                    //ignore directories or folders
                    //ignore Thumbs.db file since this probably will throw an exception
                    //another process could be using it. e.g: Explorer.exe windows process
                    if (!file.Name.Contains("Thumbs") && !Directory.Exists(localFilename))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(localFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                        {
                            // Read full stream to in-memory buffer.
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
                            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            // Create a new entry for the current file.
                            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.Name);
                            entry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

                            // set Size and the crc, because the information
                            // about the size and crc should be stored in the header
                            // if it is not set it is automatically written in the footer.
                            // (in this case size == crc == -1 in the header)
                            // Some ZIP programs have problems with zip files that don't store
                            // the size and crc in the header.
                            entry.Size = fileStream.Length;
                            fileStream.Close();

                            // Update entry and write to zip stream.
                            zipOutput.PutNextEntry(entry);
                            zipOutput.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            // Get rid of the buffer, because this
                            // is a huge impact on the memory usage.
                            buffer = null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Finalize the zip output.
                zipOutput.Finish();

                // Flushes the create and close.
                zipOutput.Flush();
                zipOutput.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void unZipFile(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

        using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(sourcePath)))
        {

            ZipEntry theEntry;
            while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
            {

                if (theEntry.Name != String.Empty)
                {
                    using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(targetPath + "\\" + theEntry.Name))
                    {

                        int size = 2048;
                        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                        while (true)
                        {
                            size = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                            if (size > 0)
                            {
                                streamWriter.Write(data, 0, size);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Forgot to mention that this will IGNORE "Thumbs.db" files at all (they are kind of useless i dont want to mess around with that data)