# How can I create a zip file using C#?

Tags: c#, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net Zip Up files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666824/net-zip-up-files)

I want to zip a `.csv` file using C#. How I can do this?

Comment: Not a real question - voting to close...

Comment: @tommieb75: The OP might not be a native speaker, but we can still help him as the basic question (how to create a zip file in .NET) is pretty clear. This question might qualify as a dupe though.

Comment: @user430607, I am sure you must have heard of [this site](http://www.google.com/). You know the one with the textbox and the two buttons at the bottom. They could be useful sometimes. Try it. Also have you noticed the textbox on the right upper corner of this page (the one next to FAQ)? It is there for a reason.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I am sure you must have heard of [this site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers). You know the one that shows the guidelines of how SO should be used. They could be useful sometimes. Try it.

Comment: @Scott, I don't agree with this. A questioner should demonstrate that he tried something to solve the problem instead of just asking for code. He should at least look if this question hasn't been already asked on this site (as this is the case here). The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) clearly states it and if you don't follow the established rules then probably this is not the right site. If we tolerate this we will end up with people posting here their customer's requirements and wanting the code. No, sorry, but I don't agree and no-one can convince me to the contrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try checking out Liam Westley's article on zipping with SharpZibLib

http://geekswithblogs.net/twickers/archive/2005/11/08/59420.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Hii...

Use this code...Please add validation on you own

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

namespace FolderZipper
{
    public static class ZipUtil
    {
        public static void ZipFiles(string inputFolderPath, string outputPathAndFile, string password)
        {
            ArrayList ar = GenerateFileList(inputFolderPath); // generate file list
            int TrimLength = (Directory.GetParent(inputFolderPath)).ToString().Length;
            // find number of chars to remove     // from orginal file path
            TrimLength += 1; //remove '\'
            FileStream ostream;
            byte[] obuffer;
            string outPath = inputFolderPath + @"\" + outputPathAndFile;
            ZipOutputStream oZipStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Create(outPath)); // create zip stream
            if (password != null && password != String.Empty)
                oZipStream.Password = password;
            oZipStream.SetLevel(9); // maximum compression
            ZipEntry oZipEntry;
            foreach (string Fil in ar) // for each file, generate a zipentry
            {
                oZipEntry = new ZipEntry(Fil.Remove(0, TrimLength));
                oZipStream.PutNextEntry(oZipEntry);

                if (!Fil.EndsWith(@"/")) // if a file ends with '/' its a directory
                {
                    ostream = File.OpenRead(Fil);
                    obuffer = new byte[ostream.Length];
                    ostream.Read(obuffer, 0, obuffer.Length);
                    oZipStream.Write(obuffer, 0, obuffer.Length);
                }
            }
            oZipStream.Finish();
            oZipStream.Close();
        }


        private static ArrayList GenerateFileList(string Dir)
        {
            ArrayList fils = new ArrayList();
            bool Empty = true;
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Dir)) // add each file in directory
            {
                fils.Add(file);
                Empty = false;
            }

            if (Empty)
            {
                if (Directory.GetDirectories(Dir).Length == 0)
                    // if directory is completely empty, add it
                {
                    fils.Add(Dir + @"/");
                }
            }

            foreach (string dirs in Directory.GetDirectories(Dir)) // recursive
            {
                foreach (object obj in GenerateFileList(dirs))
                {
                    fils.Add(obj);
                }
            }
            return fils; // return file list
        }


        public static void UnZipFiles(string zipPathAndFile, string outputFolder, string password, bool deleteZipFile)
        {
            ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(zipPathAndFile));
            if (password != null && password != String.Empty)
                s.Password = password;
            ZipEntry theEntry;
            string tmpEntry = String.Empty;
            while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                string directoryName = outputFolder;
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(theEntry.Name);
                // create directory 
                if (directoryName != "")
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                }
                if (fileName != String.Empty)
                {
                    if (theEntry.Name.IndexOf(".ini") < 0)
                    {
                        string fullPath = directoryName + "\\" + theEntry.Name;
                        fullPath = fullPath.Replace("\\ ", "\\");
                        string fullDirPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
                        if (!Directory.Exists(fullDirPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(fullDirPath);
                        FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(fullPath);
                        int size = 2048;
                        byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                        while (true)
                        {
                            size = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                            if (size > 0)
                            {
                                streamWriter.Write(data, 0, size);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        streamWriter.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            s.Close();
            if (deleteZipFile)
                File.Delete(zipPathAndFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the code formatting button in the editor toolbar to make your posting readable.

Comment: Please format your code properly. First copy-paste or write the code and then select the code and then click on the code button : )

Comment: thnxs for suggestion..will surely keep this in mind next time

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple articles with source code to show you how to zip and unzip files using C#.  It's for .NET 2.0, but should still be relevant to your problem.

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial190_Zipping-files-using-GZipStream.html
http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial191_Unzipping-compressed-files-using-GZipStream.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/).

Poke around their examples and you should be able to figure it out from there...