# how to zip a text file

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net Zip Up files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666824/net-zip-up-files)

Hi,

I am having a problem in creating a text file to zip file ,

I am creating a project which reads data file and convert it into a text file .

My code creates a text file .I want to zip the text file which is created ,

Here Is My Code,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = DayFuturesDestination + "\\" + txtSelectedDate.Text + ".txt";
    StreamWriter Strwriter = new StreamWriter(path);
}
```

Can Anyone Pls Say me how to create the zip file after creating it into a text file.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: @G Arshiya: Is it just me, or did you just post [the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234858/how-to-zip-a-text-file) in another account?

Answer (score 6):

First, you'll need to do more with your IO stream to finish writing the file you plan on zipping. The example below shows one way you could do this.

If you want to stick with only the .net framework and just want to compress and decompress, you could use [System.IO.Compression.GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), which adheres to the [GNU Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) format. Note that this is not the same as the [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) archive format. For that, you'll need a third party library, such as [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). The latter, is easier to implement, and likely a better option than GZipStream.

**For example, adapting DotNetZip's example to your code:**

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string path = DayFuturesDestination + "\\" + txtSelectedDate.Text + ".txt";
     StreamWriter Strwriter = new StreamWriter(path);
     Strwriter.Write(textToAdd);
     Strwriter.Flush();
     Strwriter.Close();

     using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
     {
         zip.AddFile(path);
         zip.Save(path + ".zip");
     }
 }
```

Comment: you might want to check out / fix the bug that someone has pointed out in this example from MSDN. It's all in the comments on the page. All in all, IMHO, GZipStream is not a great solution for this, and there are several good and smimpler open source solutions.

Comment: @stupid-phil: I agree that GZipStream is not the best option, so I've updated my post to only include the DotNetZip code example.

Comment: and +1 to you for giving him the code! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a zip library to compress the files. Try this: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Or this one: http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/ (which is used in The Orchard Project)

They both look really easy to use.

Comment: +1 because you mentioned DotNetZip before I did.