# How to find ZipEntry in zip file programmatically in C#?

Tags: c#, zip

I cannot use third party software/libraries and have a zip file that I have to read in WPF application and get the binary data (that represents the image).  That zip file contains about 7000 images and I have to find the right one by its name. How can I get the ZipEntry (analog in Java)?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html

Sincerely,

Roman

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666824/net-zip-up-files/1666844#1666844) will be a good argument why you should use a third party library?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/site/cc164129

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot use third party software/libraries

Sorry to say it but that's a ridiculous constraint.  If that's the case, you will have to struggle with whatever there is in the BCL to handle zips. And believe me, there isn't much. The [System.IO.Packaging namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.aspx) could be a good start. And if you are not using .NET 4.0, well, my condolences to you. The [zip specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) might be a good read (for me it wouldn't be a good read as a matter of fact).

I'd probably use [dotnetzip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) or [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) or something and have plenty of time solving some real world problems, not ones that have already been solved.

Comment: You are talking about corporate policy and then the CEO/President had to be fired in such case.  I envision that I'd be fired before the decision maker (a.k.a. CEO). Sorry.

Comment: @RomanKagan, so what's the policy exactly? The SEO forbids you from using open source software? He wants you to reinvent the wheels and of course all the mistakes and waste of time that this comes with this? Did this dude lost his mind? You can tell your CEO that he really should find another business as he really doesn't understand how things work in the IT industry. I mean, we, the developers, should really enlighten those illiterate in the software development type of persons. Well, what can I say? You wanna read the Zip spec? I'd rather find another job :-)

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old and so the answer.

Best answer since end of 2012 is: Use .NET 4.5 and the contained `System.IO.Compression` and  `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` namespace classes.

One of many example links you receive if you search in the internet:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381661/Creating-Zip-Files-Easily-in-NET

With Roslyn the whole framework library was published as Open Source, so AFAI understand it, you are free to extract the code from the 4.5 classes (as it should be not really system specific) and use it as a library for the earlier .NET frameworks. Maybe this would give some license advantages over using the other classes- but this has to be analyzed by you.