# will u help me to extract a zip file using C#code

Tags: c#, .net

will u help me to extract a zip file using C#code

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to see about that.

Comment: Yes..now what's the question?

Comment: In short? [No, not like this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: We will *help you*, not *do it for you* What do you got so far?

Comment: @Asha: He's asking whether someone will help him :)

Comment: i want to extract the zip file using c#code.

Comment: Use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/). And please, spend a little more time composing questions next time. People are more than willing to help you, but not when you ask like this.

Comment: This should work! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx

Comment: @Cody Gray: But there's also [ZipStorer](http://zipstorer.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @RAHUL: So have you tried anything? If not, try something.

Comment: @BoltClock: Not if someone _can_, but if they _will_!

Comment: @Richard DesLonde: Not necessarily, AFAIK this will only compress/decompress a *stream*. You'll have to figure out yourself where a file starts and where it ends.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/384955/321973

Comment: @Bobby: Yeah, there are ZILLIONS of options. It's difficult to recommend one when we're not given any more information than we are here. As for my comment, I felt like actually helping, rather than posting a sassy comment.

Comment: I _will_, you _will_, we _all will_ for a drink of _swill_!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract ZIP file in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296918/how-to-extract-zip-file-in-c)

Comment: This must be the fastest-growing comment thread ever on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also see: [What is the best/easiest way to create ZIP archive in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384955/what-is-the-best-easiest-way-to-create-zip-archive-in-net)

Comment: @BoltClick: It's growing and growing!

Comment: @Richard: And it's... stopped. :(

Comment: This comment thread is expanding quicker than a zip file in a ...

Comment: @cpedros: Are we now coming up with the candlejack jo

Comment: @BoltClock: I guess thhis is the end . . .  :-( It was fun while it lasted.

Comment: @Bobby: What is this Candlejack you spe

Answer (score 2):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is packaged as a single DLL, a single assembly. It is fully managed code, written in C#, and provides support for reading and writing Zip archive files and streams. The main type is ZipFile, featuring methods like Add(), Extract() and Save().

Comment: Sweet, never knew about it. I like it!

Comment: For this Lib i have written a helper library. It provides a service for creating packages in a fast way.
Service source code: https://github.com/nhu/Ostblock/blob/master/src/Ostblock.Ultilitys/Zipping/Services/DotNetZipService.cs

You can check out a github: https://github.com/nhu/Ostblock