# Zipping files in parts in C#

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I am looking for some example which can help me to understand how can i zip files in C# in parts i.e. if i have 20MB zip archive, I want to split the archive in **4 parts of 5MB** each.

I have gone through [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384955/what-is-the-best-easiest-way-to-create-zip-archive-in-net) and then i even looked at [DotNetZip](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DNZHelp/) library's documentation but i couldn't find any such example.

Could someone suggest? thanks,

What i am looking for that when i have those 4 files, I can extract them to the original files. So each individual part may not be a proper zip but all 4 parts should extract properly

Comment: What are you going to do with the other 10MB of zip?

Comment: Do you need each of the fragments to be a valid zip file, or are you just interested in reducing individual file size before recombining the files later?

Comment: proper zip or just compression?

Comment: sorry for typo. edited my question and added more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [ICSharpCode](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to zip the files. Once the file is zip you can use `FileStream` to save the file in small chunks. I had done this in one of my project. If you require any help, let me know.

Comment: so if i can split the zip file by reading it through a binary stream, then i can use any zip file library ... right?  at then end, it would be split up in parts using filestream

Comment: It will be like `10Mb.txt` => `10Mb.zip` (Using Zip Library) => Split file to `5MbPart1.zip` and `5MbPart2.zip` (Using Custom code, which uses `FileStream`). Do the reverse to get original file.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean split the ZIP file into multiple files after it has been zipped, meaning you have to re-combine both parts to have a valid ZIP?

You can accomplish this with 7Zip.  Here are instructions for doing it with their UI.  They also provide [an API](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) to automate the task.

http://www.linglom.com/2008/10/12/how-to-split-a-large-file-using-7-zip/

You could also just read the file as binary data, then write it to separate files using your own convention e.g. my.zip.part1of3, my.zip.part2of3, my.zip.part3of3, etc.  When ready, recombine the parts and unzip.  If you do this, the person re-assembling the parts would need a custom utility from you.