# zlib inflate() decodes only half the original payload

Tags: c#, windows-ce, zlib

I am implementing a feature that requires zlib compression/decompression on a Windows CE platform supporting C#/.NET. This is an old system and I'm struggling to get zlib deflate()/inflate() to work.  I started with zlib version 1.2.3 (which is already built and linked) but I also updated it to version 1.2.11.  Both versions exhibit the same issue.

The C# managed code pInvokes

```
zlib.compress (cBuf, cBufSize, "This is the content.", 20)
```

and it returns

```
cBufSize = 15 
cBuf = {0x0b, 0x61, 0xc8, 0x60, 0xc8, 0x64, 0x28, 0x66, 0x50, 0x80, 0x92, 0x25, 0x40, 0x3e, 0x00}
```

My C# managed code then pInvokes

```
zlib.uncompress(tBuf, tBufSize, cBuf, 15)
```

and it returns

```
tBufSize = 20
tBuf = {'T','h','i','s',' ','i','s',' ','t','h',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

For some reason only half the original byte stream is being compressed (or decompressed).  This is true for all the attempts I made to vary the original data stream.  The second half of the tBuf is always zeros!

Since I don't know anything about how zlib works, I have not tried to debug it.  I'm hoping someone has an idea what might be wrong with the zlib configuration on this very old Windows CE platform.

Comment: It would appear you are using the unmanaged zip library, in which case you should show the declaration. Is there a reason you are not using the [managed zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/384959/11683), or even the built-in DeflateStream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compressed data in `cbuf` is complete and correct raw deflate data. It decompresses to (in hex):

```
54 00 68 00 69 00 73 00 20 00 69 00 73 00 20 00 74 00 68 00
```

What you see are zero bytes in between each of the characters. You are in fact getting 20 bytes back. The problem is that the 20 bytes you provided to zlib to compress are just the first ten *characters* of your string, which are apparently encoded as two bytes each.

I don't know much about C# or Windows systems, but I would guess that your character string is being stored as UTF-16 for some reason.

Comment: `for some reason` - because that is how a .NET string is [defined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0), and what Windows [uses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/extensible-storage-engine/wchar) for `WCHAR`s too.

Comment: Doh! Well explained.  It turns out that the C# code was using a char[] -- which I'm so old school I assumed was storing 8-bits per character!  Never thought that C# would store 2 byte character codes.  It all makes sense now!  Thank you so much for the insight.

Comment: @GSerg Interesting. What a terrible choice they made. Glad I don't have to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to Mark Adler's answer. He is absolutely correct.
C# and Windows (if I'm not mistaken) store strings in 16-bit char values, which is why C# has separate `byte` and `char` types.

To make sure your string is encoded as UTF8, you can use the [Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-6.0) class.

MSDN has an example of converting to/from encodings right there.